# How to receive emails using imap in scala play using play libraries?

Tags: scala, playframework, imap

Is there any way to receive/synch emails using imap in scala play?

But i don't want to use javax.mail library

Instead i am looking for play libraries

Please suggest any ideas

Comment: I think you'd you can best use javax.mail library after all, or a scala wrapper. There's no such thing as 'native' play, for example JSON handlling in play is also based on existing Jackson JSON library, written in Scala